# Haskell: how to write code that interacts with the internals of two wrapped types?

Tags: haskell, matrix, vector, wrapper, encapsulation

I'm wondering how to create two encapsulated types that interact with each other, without exposing the internal implementation to other modules.

As an example, consider my two modules, `Vector.hs` and `Matrix.hs`, that wrap `Linear.V4` (a 4-element vector) and `Linear.M44` (a 4x4 element matrix). I wish to write a function that multiplies a `Matrix` by a `Vector`, returning a `Vector`, and using the wrapped data types to perform the operation.

In this example, in `Vector.hs` I have:

```
-- Vector.hs
module Vector (Vector, vector) where

import Linear (V4 (V4))

newtype Vector = Vector (V4 Double) deriving (Eq, Show, Read)

vector :: (Double, Double, Double, Double) -> Vector
vector (x, y, z, w) = Vector (V4 x y z w)
```

Note that I'm only exporting the new type and the factory function - the data constructor `Vector` is not exported. As far as I understand, this hides the internal implementation of `Vector` (i.e. that it's really a `V4`).

And in `Matrix.hs` I have something similar:

```
-- Matrix.hs
module Matrix (Matrix, vector)

import Linear (V4 (V4), M44)

type Row = (Double, Double, Double, Double)
newtype Matrix = Matrix (M44 Double) deriving (Eq, Show, Read)

matrix :: (Row, Row, Row, Row) -> Matrix
--matrix ((a00, a01, a02, a03), (a10, ...  ) = Matrix (V4 (V4 a00 a01 a02 a03) (V4 a10 ...))
```

These two modules can be used by client code pretty effectively - the client code is not aware that they are implemented with `Linear` data structures, and there's apparently no way for client code to exploit that (is that true?).

The problem arises when those two types need to interact with each other at the level of their wrapped types - in this particular case, multiplying a `Matrix` by a `Vector` yields a new `Vector`. However to implement this operation, the code performing it needs access to the internal implementation of both `Vector` and `Matrix`, in order to do something like this:

```
-- Matrix.hs
-- ... include earlier definitions
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

import qualified Linear.Matrix ((!*))

class MatrixMultiplication a b c | a b -> c where
  infixl 7 |*|  -- set same precedence and associativity as *
  (|*|) :: a -> b -> c

instance MatrixMultiplication Matrix Vector Vector where
  (|*|) (Matrix a) q0 =
    let (V4 x y z w) = a Linear.Matrix.!* _impl q0
    in vector (x, y, z, w)
```

To do this I need a function, `_impl`, that allows the `Matrix` module to get at the internals of `Vector`:

```
-- Vector.hs
--  ... include earlier definitions

_impl :: Vector -> V4 Double
_impl (Vector q) = q
-- also added to export list
```

So after carefully hiding the internals of `Vector` (by not exporting the data constructor function of `Vector`), it seems I must expose them with a different exported function, and the only defence I have is some documentation telling client code they shouldn't be using it. This seems unfortunate - I've effectively just renamed the data constructor.

In a language like C++, the `friend` keyword could be used to provide a function access to the private data member of one of the types. Is there a similar concept in Haskell?

I suppose I could implement both `Vector` and `Matrix` in the same module. They'd then have access to each others' data constructors. However this isn't really a satisfying solution as it just works around the issue.

Is there a better approach?

Comment: Have you looked into making a Matrix.Internal or Matrix.Private module, importing that in your Matrix.hs, and then only explicitly exporting your smart constructors? You can see examples of this in something like [Data.Map.Internal](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.2.1/docs/Data-Map-Internal.html) (look at the source too, of Data.Map.Internal versus Data.Map.Strict; the latter just exports public functions). I’ve seen many packages do this sort of thing, where some modules have no function definitions and instead reexport desired functions.

Comment: @cole ah, that sounds like a good idea, I will study that further. Thank you.

Comment: This is the canonical difference between abstract data types and classes, as discussed in [this paper](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~wcook/Drafts/2009/essay.pdf) by Cook. From how I understand it, there is fundamentally no other way than to either combine both Matrix and Vector in a joint module, so that hiding does not apply for each other, or to provide accessor functions that are "good enough" for your operations but still abstract with respect to the actual implementation of the types. See also this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3154551/4090111.

Comment: Could you implement dot products in the Vector module and export it? Then as long as you can convert rows/columns of matrices to vectors, you can compute matrix products.